# Ajax only binding once

Tags: ajax, 9

It looks like Drupal changed to a different, non jQuery version of once, and now all of our code that updates the DOM and needs to reattach the events for AJAX elements no longer reattaches them; `Drupal.attachBehaviors()` no longer works.

Comment: This sounds like https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3254840

Answer (score 1):

I have to assume that the changes to core/once library in 9.2 described here - https://www.drupal.org/node/3158256
, then also being used in core Ajax, changed the behavior. Though since we have a more global "once" class, if I understand correctly, we gain the ability to add and remove "once".

So this is what ended up working, but I'm hesitant.

```
(function (Drupal, once) {
...

/* After js (vue in this case) renders & kills event binding */

once.remove('drupal-ajax', '[data-once=drupal-ajax]');
Drupal.attachBehaviors();

...
})(Drupal, once);
```